# Как проверить ввод пользователя по всем регистрам?

Tags: java

Мне нужно что бы ввод пользователя переходил в нижний регистр, тем самым если его спросят: "Выйти?(y/n): " и он ответит - "Y" т.е большими буквами, то он всё равно проверит. Пример кода на C#:

```
Console.Write("Выйти?(y/n): ");
string quit = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
if (quit == "y") {
   break;
}
else {
   // Continue
}
```

В данном коде меня затронуло .ToLower(), как такое реализовать на JAVA?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ideone.com/5l3tzX

```
import java.io.*;

class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    if (in.readLine().trim().toLowerCase().equals("y")) {
      System.out.println("It was YES");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Что то запутанно, я только начал учить JAVA. Как то всего лишь для простой проверки много строчек кода...

Comment: Это ж джава, в ней не бывает мало кода... Впрочем, trim действительно [лишний](https://ideone.com/fsRjZn). К тому же, в твоём варианте кода примерно столько же. Я же полную программу привёл, а ты - только 2 фрагмента.

Comment: Help! Почему то ничего не работает... Всё равно выполняет ветку else хотя Y переведён в нижний регистр. 
Страница кода: http://ideone.com/ozyz4b

Comment: @FormatC, потому что ты используешь `==` вместо `.equals`. Вот же готовый код в ответе... А на ideone есть поля для stdin, который программа будет считать вводом.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

System.out.print("Выйти?(y/n): ");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String quit = in.nextLine();
String toLowerQuit = quit.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 2):

В Java у объекта типа String есть фун-ия, которая выполняет сравнение, игнорируя регистр

```
public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString)
```

Пример:

```
String input = "Y";
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
    // do positive case
} else {
    // do negative case
}
```

Comment: О, интересный вариант. Не знал, что так можно)

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "AAAAA".toLowerCase();
```

или

```
String s = "а".toUpperCase();
```